# Controllable and observable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, control-theory

The square matrices $A$ is invertible, $Q$ and $G$ symmetric positive semidefinite. Moreover, $(A,G)$ is controllable, and $(Q,A)$ is observable. I have the following question

- Is $(-A,-G)$ controllable?
- Is $(-Q,-A)$ observable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Kalman rank condition, multiplying the matrices by a constant factor does not influence controllability (and observability).